# Aptana Studio doesn't work for GIT with referenced or linked files

Tags: git, reference, aptana

I use latest Aptana 3 Studio with many projects.
I sometime use reference files between project by using:
`New > File > Advanced > and browse to file in other project`

But when my project using GIT i get message:
`Project 'name' is mapped to repository type 'com.aptana.git.core.GitRepositoryProvider' which does not support linked`

There is no option for using GIT and references/linked files?